# Mining out functions from a CPP file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I am using Visual Studio 2005, VB. I have to parse a CPP file and list all the functions that are getting called in that CPP file. Is there any built-in object that can make things easier for me or should i go about searching for () and then finding out the function calls? That is also a bit difficult (I suppose) because there is lot of function chaining also. Pls help me out..

Answer (score 0):

The only way to *reliably* do that is to parse all the C++ files, since neither Regexes, nor string manipulations can tell the difference between `()` in parameterless function invocation and overloaded `operator ()` and constructor invocation.